# SharedPreferences used for my Database

Tags: android, sqlite, gps, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create an application that stores GPS data received from a KML file by DDMS;the data is stored in the Sqlite Database.My main problem is that every time I run the application 
I store the same GPS data in the database,so is a big mess inside my database.Now someone said that I could use SharedPreferences to store a key that tells me if the database already exists assuming that the database exists then is already full.The problem is that I use a SqliteBrowser to create my database and the tabels and I use my code to add information to the tabels.So simply verifying if the tabels exists doesn't help me too much.Has anyone any ideas of how could I manage the Sqlite database so I don't store twice the same data?

Answer (score -1):

There are several possible solutions

1) Check if the data already exists before inserting new data (a simple select statement)

2) Use SQLiteOpenHelper - it provides functions for database version management
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

3) Save information about what has been added in SharedPreferences. You could have a version code or something similar in order to distinguish between different states of the database.

I would suggest that you use either 1 or 2, depending on what you really want to achieve. Maybe you can be a bit more specific about why the data is inserted several times at the moment, what type of data it is (static or dynamically created, web service, etc?)

Comment: Yes I can.Well, is simple.I'm creating an application that has two parts:1)Tracking:that means that I have to simulate a GPS module and I do that by using a KML file by DDMS.I simulate GPs data between two cities,let say,but in the same time I have to store this daata in order to rebuilt the route later.So the data I'm storing is longitude and latitude....And  every time I run my application I store this data in my database(not that I want to)....but once that I've simulated GPS between two cities and I once run the app in order to change something tiny the data is stored again

Comment: 2)The route part in which I use the data stored earlier to remake the path of the GPS data(the path of a car...)...So if my data is stored couple of times,my database is ruined...I hope I've been specific enoug.Thank you!

Comment: Ok, basically you want to record tracking data and replay it later. Should there be more than 1 route in the database at any time? If not - go with 1 or 3 - check if data is present and only insert data if no data is available. Otherwise i would suggest something more advanced - use a second "route" table in which you maintain the recorded routes and check for duplicates.

Comment: In the the database should be more than one route.I have to simulate movement for about 8 cars...even though  at this time I don't know how is that possible,cause I can't load 8 different KML files at one time in the DDMS.But,in the end,there should be about eight tables each of them describing a route....The advance way is a little bit too much for me,as I've been doing this only for a few weeks now.Thank you

Comment: BTW,how can I verify if the tables in the database are full,this would help me a lot?!Thx

Comment: Use two tables - one for routes (_id, name), one for the data (_id, long, lat, route). When you start recording (importing), add an entry in the route table for this kml. Use the _id from the route table when adding data to the data table. Implement methods to delete routes (from route table and data table) and you should be fine. As a first step just for testing, you could add a delete statement at the start of your app to clear the database before you add any data. This way you would always start out with an empty database.

Comment: You can do a select query to check whether there is data in the database or not.